# How to store and serve the time a GeoTIFF refers to

Tags: mapserver, wcs

I'm writing software that creates temperature maps as GeoTIFF files. I need to store the time to which the GeoTIFF file refers; not the raster creation time, but the time during which the temperature was as the raster data says.

What I did was store it in the GeoTIFF file as a GDAL metadata item; i.e. in a GDALMetadata private tag. The metadata item is called "TIMESTAMP".

I now need to serve the GeoTIFF file as a WCS with MapServer.

1. Is storing the time as a GDAL metadata item a good idea? Is it standard practice?
2. How is this going to be accessed with WCS? Through `DescribeCoverage`?
3. How can MapServer be told to get the metadata item from the GeoTIFF and somehow serve it to the client?

Comment: Tileindex is more native way for time queries with MapServer. Start reading from http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html#spatio-temporal-indexes and perhaps check also http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_time.html

Comment: Geoserver gives some hints near http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#mosaic-dir-and-the-configuration-files  Basically one creates a directory of 'temperature_yyyymmddHHMMSS.tif' files and enables the geoserver to parse them into a collection of files, but you could use the same naming convention to help populate and update a 'gdaltindex' shapefile for mapserver.

Answer (score 1):

I got an email asking whether I ever solved this problem, so I'm coming back to answer my own question.

I believe my question concerned [this system](https://arta.irmasys.com/), which I was building at that time:

[image]

Where it says "climate data" you can select the variable and the date, and it shows the layer on the map.

The way this works is that, whenever I have new data (this happens once per day), I run a Python script that creates a new mapfile. Since the mapfile is plain text, it's not hard to create a program that dynamically creates layers.

So each date and variable is a different layer; the variable name and the date are in the name of the layer. I have six variables and about 365 dates, because I only keep data for one year, meaning I have about 2000 layers. Clearly you can't handle these in the usual layer switcher of Leaflet or Openlayers, so I have made these extra variable/date controls, which, when changed, run some JavaScript which programmatically modifies the map.

In other words, as far as I remember, most GIS software doesn't have the feature to understand dates, or, for that matter, time series of layers, so you need to implement your own custom solution.

Comment: Kudos to you for trying to remember context and solution of a ten year old question!